# Set Qt Widget mask

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I would like to have a button with the shape of its icon image in my QT application. I'm trying to set the button mask by obtaining the mask from the used image (.png) using the alpha channel.

Here are the interested code lines:

```
QPushButton button();
QPixmap pixmap("image_path.png");
QIcon icon(pixmap);
button.setIcon(icon);
button.setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(Qt::transparent,Qt::MaskInColor));
```

The result is that the button disappears!

By doing some tests I'm sure that the mask is created rightly, where is the mistake?

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? The code snippet above suggests you're creating the `QPushButton` on the stack (you need to `new` it off if you don't want it to be removed immediately after your reference to it goes out of scope). You're also not specifying a parent `QWidget` for your button.

Comment: Hi sjwarner,thank you for your reply!
The code I wrote is not exactly the one I used in my application, where button is created in a QPushButton pointer defined as private member of the class, I just wrote these lines here to report the problem. However in this case, although button, pixmap and icon are all allocated in the stack, they should be not destroied immediately, but at the exit of the scope...

Comment: I've just tried to change button picture using a .png circular red shape on transparent background and I got a really strange,triagular-shape mask,so I think the problem is not on the code but on how function crateMask() works.
Are there any other ways to obtain a custom-shaped button? I found only other examples using createMask() and createEhuristicMask() functions but also this second one doesn't work in my application...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're using a .png with alpha like this one :
[image: transparent png]
you can set its shape as a mask like this:

```
QPushButton button;
button.resize(50,50);
button.show();

QPixmap mask("D:/shape.png");
button.setMask(mask.mask());
```

You will got a result like :
[image: result shape button]

Comment: Ok, this is the way I tried first, but it doesn'work!
In my application the QPixmap mask results strange... i tried also by usign a dummy picture composed only by a full-color regular shape (a circle) and full trasparency around, but with the same bad result.
At this point I think this can be a bug on Qt 4.6.3 (64 bit) under Linux.